# Unable to find 'getOpps' on 'compound://c.OpporutnityComponent'. in Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am new to the Lightning Experience and trying **"how to use `<aura:iteration>` in lightning components?."**

I am following site: http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2017/02/what-is-in-lightning-component-and-how.html

I am getting the below error:

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Unable to find 'getOpps' on 'compound://c.OpporutnityComponent'.
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:OpporutnityComponent}
```

**OpportunityLightningController**

```
public with sharing class OpporutnityLightningController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunities(){
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM opportunity];
        return oppList;
    }
}
```

**OpportunityComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="OpporutnityLightningController">
    <aura:attribute name="opplistAttr" type="Opportunity[]" />

    <ui:button label="Click Me" press="{!c.getOpps}" />
    <aura:iteration var="opt" items="{!v.opplistAttr}">
        <br/> {!opt.Name} <br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**OpportunityLightningAppHelper.js**

```
({
    helperMethod : function() {

    }
})
```

**OpportunityLightningAppController.js**

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        var oppt = component.get("c.getOpportunities");

        oopt.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
                component.set("v.opplistAttr", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(oppt);
    }
})
```

**EDIT-1**

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Assertion Failed!: run() cannot be called on a server action. Use $A.enqueueAction() instead. : false
Failing descriptor: {ui:button$controller$press}
```

I am getting the new error now.

Comment: I recommend you to start with trailhead

Comment: You need to rename either the function name in the Component controller or in the Component button press method binding, both should be same. So you can replace the `myAction` with `getOpps`.

Comment: For the second error, it looks like a silly typo. Just replace 'oopt' with 'oppt' to setCallback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rename either the function name in the Component controller or in the Component button press method binding, both should be same. So you can replace the `myAction` with `getOpps`.

**OpportunityLightningAppController.js**

```
({
  getOpps : function(component, event, helper) {
    var oppt = component.get("c.getOpportunities");

    oopt.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            component.set("v.opplistAttr", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(oppt);
  }
})
```

Comment: itzmukeshy7 - Now I'm getting the new error.. I've edited the post above

Comment: Please don't do that. if itzmukeshky7 solved your first problem you should acknowledge that, and if you get further problems, create a new question. Otherwise we are losing a question and answer to that question that could help others.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the below code. It should say *oppt.setCallback* and not *oopt.setCallback*

```
({
  getOpps : function(component, event, helper) {
    var oppt = component.get("c.getOpportunities");

    **oopt**.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            component.set("v.opplistAttr", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(oppt);
  }
})
```