# run() cannot be called on a server action. Use $A.enqueueAction() instead. : false Failing descriptor: {ui:button$controller$press}

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am extending the question from the link: [Unable to find 'getOpps' on 'compound://c.OpporutnityComponent'. in Lightning Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180490/unable-to-find-getopps-on-compound-c-opporutnitycomponent-in-lightning-co) as I am getting the new error

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Assertion Failed!: run() cannot be called on a server action. Use $A.enqueueAction() instead. : false
Failing descriptor: {ui:button$controller$press}
```

[image]

**OpporutnityLightningAppController.js**

```
({
    getOpps : function(component) {
        var oppt = component.get("c.getOpportunities");

        oopt.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
                component.set("v.opplistAttr", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(oppt);
    }
})
```

**OpporutnityComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="OpporutnityLightningController">
    <aura:attribute name="opplistAttr" type="Opportunity[]" />

    <ui:button label="Click Me" press="{!c.getOpportunities}" />
    <aura:iteration var="opt" items="{!v.opplistAttr}">
        <br/> {!opt.Name} <br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**OpporutnityLightningController**

```
public with sharing class OpporutnityLightningController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunities(){
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM opportunity];
        return oppList;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in your variable declaration in the javascript controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you need to do:

1. Fix typo in var name
2. Make sure your button press is calling the javascript action, not the server action
3. Perhaps remove any `getXX` type calls on the serverside

**Expansion:**

**Point 1**: You declare `var oopt...` and then you call it
            `oppt` - see the difference?

**Point 2**: You are calling the SERVER action in your component markup. You should be calling your clientside Javascript controller handler instead.

Change

```
<ui:button label="Click Me" press="{!c.getOpportunities}" />
```

To:

```
<ui:button label="Click Me" press="{!c.getOpps}" />
```

**Other things to consider**

You should also be passing in three params to the controller method. Eg:

```
getOpps : function(component, event, helper)
```

Also, make sure that this is defined in the Controller js file, not the helper js file (ie if you don't have something defined in the Controller file, then you will get this error.

How this works is you will define your handler in markup, ie `press="{!c.getOpps}

Then in your Controller - not helper - you need to define the getOpps function.

Comment: No, its  not working. I already tried that  `This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Unable to find 'getOpps' on 'compound://c.OpporutnityComponent'.
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:OpporutnityComponent}`

Comment: Well, don't change it away from that - that is definitely the correct syntax. Next thing to try, make sure you have the correct name in the Apex controller - ie `getOpportunities` is defined. After that, make sure you have the exact controller name - I see a possible typo there too

Comment: Everything looks correct to me.. method name is also used correctly..

Comment: I have had trouble before (not the same error but similar) when my server side action starts with `get`. If you change it to instead start with `load` or `init` does that help at all?

Comment: Yes, I was experimenting with that too - but it's the typo that's the big one, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I used the correct names and its working. One typo which I see need change in `OpporutnityLightningAppController.js`

```
oopt.setCallback(this, function(response){
```

to

```
oppt.setCallback(this, function(response){
```

Use this

**OpportunityLightningApp**

```
<aura:application >
    <c:OpportunityComponent></c:OpportunityComponent>
</aura:application>
```

**OpportunityComponent**

```
<aura:component controller="OpportunityLightningController" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="opplistAttr" type="Opportunity[]" />

    <ui:button label="Click Me" press="{!c.getOpps}" />

    <aura:iteration var="opt" items="{!v.opplistAttr}">
        <br/> {!opt.Name} <br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**OpportunityComponentController.js**

Here no need to use the `event` and `helper`.

```
({
    getOpps : function(component) {
        var oppt = component.get("c.getOpportunities");
        oppt.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
                component.set("v.opplistAttr", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(oppt);
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: That will only fix one of the issues. You are using part of my answer - user4567570 changed their question to reflect one of my answers. getOpps used to be getOpportunities.

Comment: @CasparHarmer - You wont need getOpps : function(component, event, helper), this will works getOpps : function(component)

Comment: Yes, I know. However, generally you should be passing those three params to a controller.